# My array is populated but I still get the error: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I've tried a lot of options to solve this, and it seems that a  lot of people get the same error, but I've tried some answers but couldn't fix.

This is how I call my second PFQueryTableViewConttoller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ExerciciosViewController *exercicios = [sb   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExerciciosViewController"];

    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Serie A"]) {
        [exercicios setTitle:[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Serie A");
        exercicios.exerciciosArray = _seriesArray;
    }
    if ([[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Serie B"]) {
        [exercicios setTitle:[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Serie B");
    }
    if ([[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Serie C"]) {
        [exercicios setTitle:[_seriesForDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Serie C");
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:exercicios animated:YES];
}
```

Now, When I click the first option, which is Serie A, it takes me to second PFQueryTableViewController, and when method NumberofRowsInSection is not present (commented), My TableView shows two items with the following code, although my array has 4 items and it should show four.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *o = _exerciciosArray[indexPath.row];
    PFObject *object2 = o[@"exercicio"];
    cell.textLabel.text = object2[@"titulo"];

    PFFile *thumbnail = object2[@"foto"];
    cell.imageView.file = thumbnail;


    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    // Colors
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    return cell;

}
```

When I insert the method NumberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _exerciciosArray.count;
}
```

If i put a Log there, it shows array populated with 4 items. Although with the above code I get crash with message: `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

I have tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you alloc init the array?

Comment: When I add the line to ViewDidLoad `_exerciciosArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` and the log at NumberOfRowsInSection `NSLog(@"TESTE ALLOC INIT %li", _exerciciosArray.count);`I get TESTE ALLOC INIT 0 in my outline, 4 times. When I don't alloc init the array in ViewDidLoad, the outline shows TESTE ALLOC INIT 4, two times. Thanks

Comment: Show us how you init and populate `_exerciciosArray`.

Comment: Basically, if I alloc init I get empty array, if I don't, the array is populated from previous VC but doesn't work anyway.

Comment: in the code above, in the first VC I create an object of the secondViewController and pass the property. with two lines ` ExerciciosViewController *exercicios = [sb   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExerciciosViewController"];`and ` exercicios.exerciciosArray = _seriesArray;` this is how I populate the array in secondViewController.

Comment: This is how I declare my property in SecondViewController: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *exerciciosArray;`

Comment: So are you saying that you've put an NSLog in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method of your ExerciciosViewController and it shows 4 objects in _exerciciosArray.count?  If that's the case, _exerciciosArray.count is not empty during cellForRowAtIndexPath: and the error may be coming from elsewhere...

Comment: Yes, that is the case, just before the crash, the log counts 4 objects, but the next line, which is `return _exerciciosArray.count`is when it crashes. The array is only populated if I don't alloc and init in this Viewcontroller, If I do alloc init in ViewDidLoad, it is empty when this log occurs. Thanks

Comment: Wait, so are you setting _exerciciosArray.count in both the ExerciciosViewController's viewDidLoad and in the previous view controller's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: No, in the previous ViewController I try to populate the array with another array.

Comment: But what do you mean by this: "The array is only populated if I don't alloc and init in this Viewcontroller, If I do alloc init in ViewDidLoad, it is empty when this log occurs."

Comment: The error message refers to a mutable array. Is _seriesArray in your first controller a mutable array? You should add an exception breakpoint to your app to pinpoint the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened, I've tried a lot of things. What I did was, instead of making my class a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController (parse.com), I just made it a subclass of UITableViewController. The code was almost the same. Didn't have to alloc init the array in the second view controller.

Everything is working now. Thanks a lot for helping.